# Images are not displaying in media library even though its name and alt text is showing

Tags: wordpress

[image]

My website is not displaying any image, in console its giving "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" error, even though when I go to media library section, images are there but in blank and when I click to images its alt text is coming.
[image]

Comment: any cache plugin included?

Comment: No, I have even tried to check after disabling all the plugins

Comment: Have you tried the File URL? Copy URL and try to open somewhere, if files are existing so make sure that your thumbnails are existing or deleted by some other plugins? Suggestion is, regenerate the thumbnails if only thumbnails are missing.

Comment: When i do that, in network tab its showing status 302, too many redirects

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem on staging website. First, I have **delete .htaccess** file then go to ***settings->permalinks->save changes***. It will automatically create a new .htaccess file. Refresh your browser to see the changes.
Reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/404-when-fetching-image-from-wp-content-uploads